# Not able to run gcloud run deploy from Vertex AI Pipelines

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have been trying to deploy a model to cloud run but I am continuously getting a permission error. Tried using all the available suggestions and answers but had no success. Finally gave the owner access to the service accounts but no success.

screenshot of what I am trying to do.

[image]

the code

```
storage_client = storage.Client()

bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix)  # Get list of files
for blob in blobs:
    filename = blob.name
    if not filename.endswith("/"):
        blob.download_to_filename(dl_dir+filename.split("/")[-1])  # Download

bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(tar_path.split("/")[0])
blob = bucket.blob("/".join(tar_path.split("/")[1:]))
blob.download_to_filename("/tmp/model_serving/model.pth.tar")

os.chdir("/tmp/model_serving/")
print("############### ", os.listdir())

os.system("gcloud run deploy --port 5050 --allow-unauthenticated --region us-central1 darts-rnn-from-pipeline --source .")
```

error I am getting

[image]

I am able to run the command outside the pipeline without any errors.
I am also able to run the storage and bq clients inside the pipeline without any errors.
But only this command I am not able to run.

Comment: Are you using a compute service account or did you create a new service account for this scenario, and what are the permissions attached to your service account? Where did you run your code? Were you using Vertex AI workbench?

Comment: Voting to close for lack of detail as there was no reply to the previous comment from 1 year ago.